# Suggestions on automating Sharepoint workflows to process Excel Files

Tags: python, azure, automation, azure-functions, power-automate

So I have task of automating a workflow such that:

`Whenever an excel file (a.xlsx) is added/modified to the SharePoint Folder ->`

`My custom data extractor code will process this excel file ->`

`Extracted data will be stored as a new excel file (b.xlsx) in another folder on SharePoint.`

This has to be achieved using Power Automate or Logic Apps with Azure Functions. But I am not able to wrap my head around how to go about this.

Has anyone implemented something like this before?

PS: My code is in Python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So, when a.xlsx is created or updated, you want to perform some action to that file before save as b.xlsx in another folder.

If it is something that cannot be done just using Power Automate/Logic Apps, you can insert a azure function to your flow in 2 different ways:

1. Using an Azure Function Action ([more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=consumption#create-functions-from-inside-logic-app-workflows))
2. Using an Http Action ([more here](https://azurelessons.com/call-azure-function-from-flow/))

[image]

You will need an azure function of type http trigger
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python

If you can share what you need to do before save as b.xlsx I may be able to help more